# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Without Error Message

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I published my first app on Google Play. So rarely it's crashes with error below. When I tested it in multiple devices I didn't encountered any problem. I'm not sure but I presume Firebase initiliaze causes this problem? How am I can find the issue?

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:7251)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6787)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6704)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1913)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7664)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:592)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty (Preconditions.java:8)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.checkRequiredFirebaseOptions (FirebaseInstanceId.java:52)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance (FirebaseInstanceId.java:2)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance (FirebaseInstanceId.java:1)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.Store.checkForRestore (Store.java:15)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.Store.<init> (Store.java:5)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.<init> (FirebaseInstanceId.java:16)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.<init> (FirebaseInstanceId.java:8)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar.lambda$getComponents$0$Registrar (Registrar.java:26)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar$$Lambda$0.create (Registrar.java)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0 (ComponentRuntime.java:69)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get (ComponentRuntime.java:4)
  at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get (Lazy.java:53)
  at com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer.get (AbstractComponentContainer.java:27)
  at com.google.firebase.components.RestrictedComponentContainer.get (RestrictedComponentContainer.java:83)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar.lambda$getComponents$0$FirebaseMessagingRegistrar (FirebaseMessagingRegistrar.java:21)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar$$Lambda$0.create (FirebaseMessagingRegistrar.java)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0 (ComponentRuntime.java:69)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get (ComponentRuntime.java:4)
  at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get (Lazy.java:53)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents (ComponentRuntime.java:158)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis (FirebaseApp.java:563)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:304)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:268)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:253)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate (FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:2388)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:2358)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo (FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:7246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6787)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6704)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1913)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7664)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:592)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:947)
```